# Java parse error when converting "9632580147" to int

Tags: java, android, string, int, type-conversion

In my java code, I have a string `9632580147`, and when I convert it into a int, using this code:

```
            try{  
                sNumberInt = Integer.parseInt(sNumber);  
            } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {  
                Log.d("NUMBER", nfe.getMessage());
                return;  
            }
```

It goes into the catch block saying `Invalid int: "9632580147"`...
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: remove the `"`s around your numbers.

Comment: The string itself doesn't have quotes, I just put it here.

Comment: can u post ur string ?

Comment: int max value is  `2,147,483,647.`

Comment: The string is `9632580147`....

Comment: The better way to fix all those kind of issues is taking a book about java basics, I would recommend you the SunCertifiedJavaProgrammer Study Guide SE6, is the best...

Comment: that's because it is not an int ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you type

```
int sNumber = 9632580147;
```

into your code, the compiler will tell you:

The literal 9632580147 of type int is out of range

The reason is that your number is too big to fit into an int, use a long instead.

Answer (score 5):

Max value of `int` is `2147483647` and you are trying to pass `9632580147` which is greater. Try maybe `Long.parseLong(sNumber)`

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are passing value larger than 32 bits: 
9632580147 = 1000111110001001011000001000110011 (34 bits)

Answer (score 2):

`Integer` max value is 2147483647.  If you want to part that number, you need to parse it into a `Long`.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum value of the integer in Java is `2147483647` while your input `9632580147` is greater. Instead, use a long data type:

```
long sNumberLong = Long.parseLong(sNumber);
```